# Conditional serialization with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Is it possible to conditionally serialize a property from an object using protobuf-net?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate A LOT on what you want. Under which conditions? (Most likely, the answer is 'no' - how would the client know whether or not the server sent it or not). You can create a two classes - one with all the mandatory properties, and one with the property that is only occasionally there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

protobuf-net supports the standard conditional serializers patterns, so for property `Foo`, a method like `bool ShouldSerializeFoo()` or a property `bool FooSpecified` (with at least a getter) should work fine. These same techniques are supported my multiple serialization and UI frameworks.

Or more simply, for value-type properties, you can just use `Nullable<T>`. A null value will not be serialized.