# Is there a way to treat some values as null when serializing a Protobuffer? (.net)

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

So, I would like to treat -1, "" and NaN as null values when serializing some fields in a protobuffer.  This is to deal with legacy code.  Right now I'm populating the a protobuffer based on a C# object I'm provided, and a number of the properties have these values which indicate a kind of `null` value.  I'd like very much not to have write and maintain a ton of `if` checks to see if the field holds one of these so called `null` values.

Is there some kind of .NET protobuffer serialization option that would silently treat these values and null and not serialize them?

For clarity this is .NET 4.5 with protoc 2.6.1.

Comment: Just write a function that tests for those and return null( or if it's a string response, replace them with null)  if they match. The call it when you need to check

Comment: Can you share a [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the type you are serializing, and what you are doing currently?

Comment: Also, is this a duplicate of [Conditional serialization with protobuf-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469388/conditional-serialization-with-protobuf-net)?